# My first gmail gadget isn't showing

Tags: gmail, google-gadget

I'm trying to add a sidebar gadget to Gmail using the guidance given in https://developers.google.com/gmail/sidebar_gadgets. To get started, I've taken a copy of the Hello World file, changed the text a bit and placed it in http://bachtrack.com/mygooglegadget.xml. I've added it to the list of gadgets in my Gmail settings, as specified - it's visible on the settings page.

Trouble is, nothing else happens at all. There's no visible gadget anywhere in my sidebar as a result of this, in any of a variety of screens.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code - I really don't think I changed anything other than the text, and it appears to parse OK...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Google gadget example from Bachtrack" /> 
  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
       Hello from my Bachtrack Gmail gadget!
     ]]>
  </Content> 
</Module>
```

By the way, I think this is the same as the unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378334/gmail-gadget-doesnt-appear-sidebar but I'm posting it separately to include the tag google-bigquery.

Comment: Use https for hosting xml

Comment: How is your issue related to Google BigQuery?

Comment: I read on a help page somewhere in the Google developers area that Google provided support for these problems requiring my to use this tag in StackOverflow. But it looks like I got this wrong and that this referred to some other bit of the page. My apologies.